# CPanel Won't Serve Files Owned By Other Users

Tags: permissions, webserver, file-permissions, cpanel, whm

I have an automated CI environment running as a non-root user which writes files to a www directory managed by WHM/CPanel.  The files get there OK and if I chown them after they've been copied over will work fine and be visible online, however leaving the username as the CI environment's build agent user blocks WHM/CPanel from serving up the files.

I've heard previously that WHM/CPanel will check the file owner as a safety check to make sure it doesn't serve up non-web content, but is there a way to bypass this?  (Ideally by adding the build agent user to a list of users which can post, alternatively by just disabling the check for the site or across WHM as a whole?)

This is on Centos 7 (SELinux.)

Comment: What PHP handler are you using?  You can see this in WHM » Software » MultiPHP Manager.

Comment: @Deltik this shouldn't be relevant because it's just static html pages, not PHP.